# DialogFlow - send custom payload for telegram such as video

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Folks.

I need to send video file from dialog flow as URI to telegram user.

Tried:

```
{
  "telegram": {
    "video": "https://"
  }
}
```

Tried to guess JSON format for fulfillment message via "payload" but nothing works.

And I could not find documentation about the required format.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently you cannot send a video in Telegram. According to [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/telegram) the only supported rich responses are Image, Card, Quick Replay, and Custom Payload (which includes text and hyperlink). If you want to send the link here's the format of custom response:

```
 {
  "telegram": {
    "text": "You can read about *entities* [here](/docs/concept-entities).",
    "parse_mode": "Markdown"
  }
 }
```