# How to embedded video as a response under telegram using googleflow platform?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Need help. I just newly learnt coding and new to google dialogflow.

Can i know how to code under custom payload to play a video in telegram using google dialogflow platform? Tried using sendvideo and is not working..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DialogFlow - send custom payload for telegram such as video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63162266/dialogflow-send-custom-payload-for-telegram-such-as-video)

Comment: yes. it did. thank you Gray_Rhino